# Matching strings in awk taking the input fro the text files

Tags: string, awk, pattern-matching

I want to ask a question regarding the strings matching in awk language. I have multiple strings in a `file` like :

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
.
.
.
```

I want to match these strings in the other text file.

Is there an easy way to do that using awk? Thanks for any help.

Comment: at least awk is one possibility to do it. however it would be good if you could paste some example input and your expecting output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is an easy way of doing this in awk.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}($0 in a)' file_1 file_2
```

where `file_1` is your string file and `file_2` is your search file.

Comment: Can you post some sample data form your two files and provide your desired output?

Comment: Hi jaypal, i have a big file with strings like this

Comment: `a` is an array where we store entire line from `file_1`. `$0 in a` does a test on `file_2` to see if any line from `file_2` is present in our array. If it does then we print it.

Comment: Actually i wanted the other way round.to see what lines in file_1 are there in file_2.if it matches then print hose lines present in file_2 and print those lines of file_2.

Comment: @Sonal In that case just change the filenames at the end. Instead of file1 and file2 you can do file2 and file1.

Comment: Hi jaypal i figured out something for the problem and i have posted the answer.But thanks a lot to you.

Answer (score 0):

If string from 1st column of file1 has to matched to 4th column of another file2 and all the lines (matched only) are to printed. than i guess this is an easiest way to do in awk.

```
awk -F "field seperater" '{a[$1=1]} a[$4]' file1 file2.
```

Comment: If thats the case, I would suggest to do something like this - `awk -F"field separator" '{a[$1];next} ($4 in a)' file{1,2}`

Comment: ya your way is definitely better.Thanks.